# Constant current source with high Vce voltage

Tags: bjt, current-source, pnp

At the moment I implemented a current source with two FMMT560 for about 1 mA. These types allow -500V Vce. I expect startup peaks of 520 V which is too much. Are there any current sources which use PNP types but split Vce over two parts? I think I have to use four transistors for this.

**Edit1**:
Now I used the comments to produce a circuit like this and simulated it. [image]. The problem is that Vce over Q1 is not decreased but that is what I want.

Comment: Not perfectly clear what you are talking about without a schematic, but can't you just cascode the main PNP if you can take the hit in compliance voltage?

Comment: I use a current source like this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185677/limiting-current-through-zener-shunt-reference-by-pnp-current-source but ground is connected to the negative rail.

Comment: Gustavo, you could consider the addition of a BJT in cascode to distribute the voltage tension. If you have a handy supply rail available for it. If needed, I could show you what I mean. (But you may already know.)

Comment: One more comment, Gustavo. I take it that you currently use ***two*** devices because you are distributing dissipation over the pair. (Am I correct?) You could re-arrange the two in a way that still distributes the dissipation but now also provides protection against the start-up peaks using one of them in cascode to the other. Just saying.

Comment: If you are dealing with a large voltage and a small current, why not just use a resistor as the "current source"? My old boss used to design high-voltage amplifiers (flyback for CRT televisions) and he always recommended this technique when the voltages were high enough. It eliminates problems like breakdown voltages and parasitic capacitance, and with a large voltage the current source is surprisingly stable. Here you could just have a 500k resistor to your -500V supply, and you should have a stable 1mA current source. Make sure the resistor can dissipate 0.5W of power.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub The problem may be (the OP needs to clarify) that a very wide compliance voltage is needed. And that this is why they went to so much bother to create such a large magnitude rail in the first place. (It's what I assumed, anyway, probably because of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/332070/38098).)

Comment: Normal operation rail is 370V for a discrete opamp.